# PHP fread not working after successful fopen, write and fclose

Tags: php, fopen, fread

It's early in the morning and I'm just not getting this:

The following code works, and file is placed on the server:

```
$filename = $ioid . "_" . time();
$fp = fopen("$filename.csv", "w+");
foreach ($csv as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

But this doesn't work straight after (file is 105k):

```
$fp2 = fopen("$filename.csv", "r");
$output = fread($fp2, 1000000000000);
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $output;
fclose($fp2);
```

Nothing is read, and nothing is printed to the page.

What obvious thing am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `fread($fp2, 1000000000000)` tries to allocate **1 terabyte** big buffer to read the file into and obviously hits allowed memory limit, unless you're on a 32-bit platform where **integer overflow** occurs. Either way it isn't working.

If you want read a whole file to the output buffer and do that fast, use `readfile()` like so:

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
readfile("$filename.csv")
```

Be sure to check the error log next time.

Also if you don't plan to store resulting files on disk I recommend you to remake your script to use a safer approach:

```
$fp = tmpfile(); // creates a handle for a temporary file with a unique name
foreach ($csv as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
rewind($fp);
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.csv");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp); // this removes the file
```

Comment: Bingo - thanks. Not really dealt with file handling before so the second part very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The probkem is in `fread` argument. Your code produces:

```
Warning: fread() [function.fread]: Length parameter must be greater than 0
```

when changing 1000000000000 to 1000 for example it works. so: use it this way:

```
$output = file_get_contents("filename.csv");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $output;
```

Comment: 1000000000000 is a valid integer at 64-bit platforms

Comment: @sanmai, yes, but if OP gets an error it means he's on 32-bit. i just wanted to point that the problem was in this number. but you was faster

Comment: there's also an error of different sort at 64-bit platforms, see my answer